# Extract specific string in between 2 characters using Salesforce formula

Tags: formula, substring, find

I want to extract the time in this below chat transcript body field.
Below is the sample value in Chat Transcript Body field :
And I want to take the value 13s

```
<p align="center">Chat Started: Thursday, March 23, 2023, 19:28:13 (+0800)</p><p align="center">Chat Origin: Chat-Low</p><p align="center">Agent tina Z</p>(13s) tina Z: Hi<br>( 50s ) HS: 你好吗<br>( 1m 8s ) HS: 我要断网络了<br>( 4m 23s ) HS: 我已经断网了，你还在吗？<br>( 4m 32s ) tina Z: 太好了，你回来了<br>
```

could anyone please help me to write the formula in Salesforce.
I have tried the below code and its not working. I am not well understand about how to put the index here. Can we get it without using index. because here the time is dynamic

```
MID(
Test__c,
FIND("</p> (", Test__c) + LEN("</p> ("),FIND(")", Test__c, 
FIND("</p> (", Test__c)) - FIND("</p> (", Test__c) - LEN("</p> (")
)
```

Thank you,
Thiru

Comment: so what have you tried? we're not a code writing service  here - but ready to help if you demonstrate what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated the question with my tried solution

Comment: Sounds like a simple job for REGEX to me.

Comment: I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer :

```
MID(
   {!$Record.Body},
   FIND("</p>(", {!$Record.Body}) + 5,
   FIND(")", {!$Record.Body}, FIND("</p>(", {!$Record.Body})) - FIND("</p>(", {!$Record.Body}) - 5
)
```